# Find objects in one list based on objects in another list in Python

Tags: python, list

How do I find objects in one list based on objects in another list?

Here I have a .txt file with multiple sites from which I can download the necessary file by name.

If I need a single file or some specific I could download it directly by choosing the needed file, but what I have is a separate list of files that matches the download site's last characters

**The list of necessary files:**

```
print(lis)
 Out[96]: ['folder1_file_1', 'folder1_file_2', 'folder1_file_3', 'folder2_file_3']
```

**The txt file with sites which needs to be downloaded:**
[image]

How can I find these four files in the .txt file and download them?

```
['folder1_file_1', 'folder1_file_2', 'folder1_file_3', 'folder2_file_3']
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
lis = ['folder1_file_1', 'folder1_file_2', 'folder1_file_3', 'folder2_file_3']


site = 'W:\storage_public_sites_all.txt'
with open(site) as f:
    urllist = f.readlines()
urllist = [x.strip() for x in urllist]

for n in urllist:
    b = [item for item in n if item.__contains__(lis)]

    # HOW TO FIND CORRESPODNING FILES BY NAMES IN LIS

    dest_folder = r'W:\download'
```

**WORKING SOLUTION from @ljdyer:**

```
lis = ['folder1_file_1', 'folder1_file_2', 'folder1_file_3', 'folder2_file_3']
destination = r'W:\download'

site = 'W:\storage_public_sites_all.txt'
with open(site) as f:
    urllist = f.readlines()
urllist = [x.strip() for x in urllist]

files = [file for file in urllist for url in lis if url in file]
for file in files:
    print(file)
    import wget
    wget.download(file, out=destination)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from pathlib import Path

lis = ['folder1_file_1', 'folder1_file_2', 'folder1_file_3', 'folder2_file_3']

site = r'W:\storage_public_sites_all.txt'
with open(site) as f:
    urldict = {Path(urlparse(line).path).stem: line.strip() for line in f}

for file in lis:
    print(f"{file}: {urldict[file]}")
    # do stuff here
```

Output:

```
folder1_file_1: https://storage.public.eu/opendata/files/folder1/folder1_file_1.jpg
folder1_file_2: https://storage.public.eu/opendata/files/folder1/folder1_file_2.jpg
folder1_file_3: https://storage.public.eu/opendata/files/folder1/folder1_file_3.jpg
folder2_file_3: https://storage.public.eu/opendata/files/folder2/folder2_file_3.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get all the txt files from the list of URLs in a single list comprehension:

```
files = [file for file in files for url in urllist if url in file]
```

then you can just iterate over your list of .jpg file names to download the files:

```
for file in files:
    ...
```